# Linking Arduino With Twitter

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

My project is having Arduino with my WiFi shield connect to Twitter and look for any messages that other users have tweeted at me that contain a certain color, (I.E. @myTwitterHandle I want red) and then changes an RGB LED to become that color.

I have been searching online for different methods, and found a few different solutions which I could use as a starting point. However, these apparently call to an old Twitter API that is not supported anymore (support stopped mid 2013).

One solution I came across was to use node-red as well as MQTT.  I am not too familiar with these programs.

Does anyone know how to have Arduino parse a twitter account for mentions containing certain strings and have it print to LED? Any help with be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Twitter 1.1 API requires OAuth authorization over SSL, for which Arduino is under-powered.

You will need to write a proxy application, which would parse the tweets and then send a RGB color value to your Arduino.

You should split your project into three parts.

1. Retrieving tweets with the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation).
   You can get some library to do it for you.
2. Communicating with your Arduino.
   Just try to send an arbitrary color to your Arduino over internet.
3. And finally joining first two pieces of code together.

And if you get stuck somewhere, you can always ask for help here on StackExchenge.